# transpose rows into columns without aggregate (pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
( 
      [ID] int,
      [FORMID] int,
      [NAME] VARCHAR(30), 
      [VALUE] VARCHAR(30), 
      [CREATED] datetime,
);

INSERT INTO yourtable ([ID], [FormID], [NAME], [VALUE], [CREATED])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'First N', 'A b', '2018-01-01'),
    (2, 1, 'Last N', 'c d', '2018-01-01'),
    (3, 1, 'Email', 'a@GM', '2018-01-01'),
    (4, 2, 'First N', 'a b2', '2018-01-01'),
    (5, 2, 'Last N', 'c d2', '2018-01-01'),
    (6, 2, 'Email', 'c@GM2', '2018-01-01');
```

I need to output of something like this, if additional column need to be added, won't mind.

```
First N | Last N
--------+--------
A b     | c d
a b2    | c d2
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: This question can't be answered, because your table is lacking a column(s) which relates a given first name, last name, and email.  That is, we don't know how to connect a given first and last name together.

Comment: with the values "First N" and "Last N", that is how it has been structured by predecessors

Comment: There are no "predecessors" in your table, because there is no column which dictates such an ordering.  In general, there is **no** internal order to a SQL table. You need to add more data if you want an answer here.

Comment: @Developer . . . You need an identity or `createdAt` column in the table to tie the rows together.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry there are other additional columns in table, I just strip them to keep it simple, did not realize it has become too simple to solve the question :) update the question now

Answer (score 0):

Split your table into two tables as below and based on auto increment column you can join them to get combibnation of first and last name.
Ofcourse I am assuming a **LOT** of things here from your table data :)

```
declare @yourtable table
    ([NAME] varchar(30), [VALUE] varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO @yourtable
    ([NAME], [VALUE])
VALUES
    ('First N', 'A b'),
    ('Last N', 'c d'),
    ('Email', 'a@GM'),
    ('First N', 'a b2'),
    ('Last N', 'c d2'),
    ('Email', 'c@GM2')

    declare @firstName table(id int identity(1,1),[First N] varchar(100))
    declare @lastName table(id int identity(1,1),[Last N] varchar(100))

    Insert Into @firstName([First N])
    select value 
    from @yourtable where name= 'First N'

    Insert Into @lastName([Last N])
    select value 
    from @yourtable where name= 'Last N'

    SELECT [First N],[Last N] FROM  @firstName f LEFT JOIN  @lastName l on f.id = l.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a best way, but for timebeing I used sub queries

```
Select
   formid as fid,
   (Select value from yourtable where Name = 'First Name' and formid=fid) as FirstName,
   (Select value from yourtable where Name = 'Last Name' and formid=fid) as LastName
From yourtable
```